# taking a manual elasticsearch snapshot, is it avaible after upgrade

Tags: elasticsearch, snapshot, aws-elasticsearch

We are using AWS ElasticSearch and are currently looking to update it to 6.8 from version 6.3.

I have done a manual snapshot as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-snapshots.html

Now, if we upgrade are we still able to access the v6.3 snapshots, should we want to revert back to that version for some reason?

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As snapshots are saved on S3, they are not affected or lost after upgrade